# Transcendence degree of the function field of a variety is same as the krull dimension of its arbitry local ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My Question is simple

Let $X$ be a variety ; that is, a prevariety whose diagonal is closed, or, integral separated scheme of finite type over some algebraically closed $k$.

Let $k(X)$ be the function field and $x \in X$ be the arbitrary point.

Q. Then $tr.deg._{k}k(X)$ = dim $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ ?

My question is originated from the Donu Arapura's "Algebraic geometry over complex numbers", p.29 ;

[image]

I'm trying to understand the bottom underlined statement

; i.e., he argues that (where $m_{x}$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$)

$$ \operatorname{dim}_{k}T_{X,x} := \operatorname{dim}_{k}m_{x}/m_{x}^2 = tr.deg._{k}k(X)$$ if and only if $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regular local ring ; i.e.(since $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is noetherian), $\operatorname{dim}_{k}m_{x}/m_{x}^2 = \operatorname{dim} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$

So, to show the equivalence, it suffices to show that $tr.deg._{k}k(X)$ = dim $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. And here is the step that I stuck.

C.f. In the Gortz, Algebraic Geometry I, p.126. we have a theorem ;

[image]

(In this theorem, dim$X$ is definend as the topological dimension, not as $tr.deg._{k}k(X)$.)

By the theorem, if $x \in X$ is closed, then we can deduce that $tr.deg._{k}k(X)$ = dim $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. But if $x \in X$ is not closed?

Or for variety, is there a way to bypass and deduce $tr.deg._{k}k(X)$ = dim $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$?

Comment: This is true only if $ x $ is a closed point, in which case both sides equal the dimension of $ X $.

Comment: O.K. I see. Maybe, he does not point out closedness of $x$ for the equivalence